# Unable to connect mongodb to node.js

Tags: node.js

```
apoorva@apoorva-latitude-e6410:~/Documents/project$ node package.json
apoorva@apoorva-latitude-e6410:~/Documents/project$ npm install
npm WARN package.json @ No description
npm WARN package.json @ No repository field .
npm WARN package.json @ No README data
npm ERR! Linux 4.4.0-51-generic
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! node v0.12.2
npm ERR! npm  v2.7.4

npm ERR! version not found: mongodb@3.2.11
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /home/apoorva/Documents/project/npm-debug.log
```

How to solve this problem?I tried a lot but unable to fix this problem.

Comment: What `/home/apoorva/Documents/project/npm-debug.log` says?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are referring to wrong MongoDB version on npm. Latest stable version of MongoDB on npm is **2.2.12**. Please refer https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongodb